# Automorphism and Symmetric Groups on a Finite Set

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $X$ be a finite set with $n$ elements. Is it necessarily true that $\text{Aut}(X) = S_n$? Here $S_n$ is the finite symmetric group of order $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the category of sets, bijections are isomorphisms. So permutations are automorphisms.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!